# existence of partial derivative and ordinary derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

My questions has 2 parts.

(a). Can we define ordinary derivative for a multi variable function(if z=xy, can we define dz/dx)?

(b). Can we define partial derivative for a single variable function(if z=f(x) and x=f(t),will the partial derivative of z with respect to x  & partial derivative of z with respect to t & partial derivative of x with respect to t & partial derivative of x with respect to z be defined or will they be 0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your first question would be the [Jaccobi matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant), consisting of all the partial derivatives of each coordinate of the function. (So, for your example $f(x,y) = xy$, it would be a row vector). This is different from a partial derivative, which looks more like the ordinary one dimensional derivative, but partial derivatives give you less information; for instance, a function might have all partial derivatives existing, without being continuous! (In that case, it wouldn't be fully 'differentiable' in the full 'multi-dimensional' sense of the word, without getting too technical.)

For your second one, what you've got is a function nested in another, $f(g(t))$. For this, you can use the chain rule, which still holds in higher dimensions, using the derivative mentioned earlier (i.e. a matrix). However, this wouldn't be a partial derivative, as each function has only one coordinate, so actually this is just the ordinary chain rule.